# disable back button when logout in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page and problem is that when I click the logout button, it redirects to the login page but when press the back button it show the previous pages, so how I can handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate code that uses one of the techniques defined [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/buttons/article.php/3478911/Disabling-the-Back-Button.htm).

Answer (score 1):

```
if you handle session manually in your application than you remove all session variable from your application and put the following java script in your page  logout page

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="noBack();"
    onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();">
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the response header in the focusing page, (i.e) in the login page.
ensure the following code in the login.jsp page,

Coding:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");    
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
```

/*
Note:
 place this code above any of those code
*/

but i don't know wheather the same functionality can be done using javascript/jquery,"awww... i don't think so!!!"